# Vuex registerModule method registers an empty module

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have two modules. One load statically, the other dynamically.

**StaticLoadingStore.js:**

```
export default {
        namespaced: false,
        state() {
            return {
                propertySL: 'Some value from a statically loaded module',
            }
        },
        getters: {
            getPropertySL(state) {
                return state.propertySL
            },
        },
    }
```

**DynamicLoadingStore.js**

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state() {
        return {
            propertyDL: 'Some value from a dynamically loaded module',
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getPropertyDL(state) {
            return state.propertyDL
        },
    },
}
```

Dynamically loaded module shows that it is empty. Why?

**HelloWorld.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>SL</h1>
        <h5>propertySL:</h5>
        <p>{{ propertySL }}</p>
        <h5>stateSL:</h5>
        <code>{{stateSL}} </code>

        <h1>DL</h1>
        <h5>propertyDL:</h5>
        <p>{{ propertyDL===undefined?'undefined':propertyDL }}</p>
        <!-- return undefined -->
        <h5>stateDL:</h5>
        <code>{{stateDL}} </code>
        <!-- return {} -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import SLModule from '../StaticLoadingStore'

    const DLModule = () => import('../DynamicLoadingStore.js');

    export default {
        data: () => ({
            stateSL: '',
            stateDL: '',
        }),
        computed: {
            propertySL() {
                return this.$store.getters['getPropertySL']
            },
            propertyDL() {
                return this.$store.getters['dlModule/getPropertyDL']
            },
        },
        created() {
            this.$store.registerModule('slModule', SLModule);
            this.stateSL = JSON.stringify(this.$store.state['slModule'], null, 2);
            this.$store.registerModule('dlModule', DLModule());
            this.stateDL = JSON.stringify(this.$store.state['dlModule'], null, 2);
        }
    }
</script>
```

My knowledge in vue and js is very limited, and I ask the question through Google translator, so I apologize in advance for incompetence.

Without waiting for an answer, he began to experiment.

**That's how it worked.**

**DynamicLoadingStore.js**

```
...
       async created() {
            const moduleLoader = await DLModule();
            this.$store.registerModule('dlModule', moduleLoader.default);
...
```

But why this is not as recommended in the examples is not clear.

**New problem**. Reactivity does not work. alert(this.$store.getters['dlModule/getPropertyDL']) 
gives expected data.

But the propertySL in template is empty. Tell me what's wrong, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why this is not as recommended in the examples is not clear.

If you talking about this official guide [Dynamic Module Registration](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration). I think the author doesn't want to specify how to get the module since there are a lot of ways to do.

In your example I think both modules should call dynamic module, static module is the module that declared at store creation.

But you import it with different methods which are static import and dynamic import. You can read more about import from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

To use dynamic import, there is no need to wrap import statement with function:

```js
...
await import('../DynamicLoadingStore.js')
...

...
// This will useful when you use dynamic component
() => import('../DynamicLoadingStore.js')
...
```

> New problem. Reactivity does not work.
>   alert(this.$store.getters['dlModule/getPropertyDL']) gives expected
>   data.
>
> But the propertySL in template is empty. Tell me what's wrong, please.

If you register `slModule` before `dlModule`, the `propertySL` should still work fine but not `propertyDL`.

The reason is this is the how computed property works, since you are using `async created` instead of `created`, the computed property doesn't wait until `async created` finished. So when Vue try to compute the dependency of the property it cannot do correctly because your getters will return undefined.

You can solve this problem by use another data to trigger computed property to recompute like this:

```js
this.dlModuleReady && this.$store.getters["dlModule/getPropertyDL"];
```

See [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-galileo-5jsxh).